# Wordpress browser-cached content

Tags: wordpress, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm providing premium content with an expiration date on my blog, and I would like to force the browser not to cache it. On the backend-side there're links that redirect to video content, and these links expire. But if somebody adds a redirected link to favorites, then they can still see the content. 
So far I tried setting up meta tags in html, adding some randomly generated strings both in markup and in the url as a get param, but somehow browsers are ignoring it. I also thought of ajax loading the content, but than I think it'd get too complicated for content-person to maintain the page.
The content are videos stored on third party's server.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this the other way around. Try setting a cookie whenever you grant access to a user and deleting it when the content expires.

Comment: How do I delete the cookie then, you mean the situation when the user gets the cookie set on entering the content with the expiration date, and checking if the cookie exists in order to display the content? How about the case when the user has the content already cached in the browser? I'm not quite clear about it.

Comment: You can do a check on the property **expires** of the cookie each time the user gets to that page. If the user has downloaded you content offline then there isn't much you can do. 

Another angle would be to find a video player that would make the caching / saving of your content very hard.

Comment: Maybe this player thing is a solution - I get that once the user accesses the content then they can do whatever they want, but my customer doesn't hence this question ;-) Thanks